# How To Access All Indexes In Nested Array (Vue-chartjs)

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

so I am trying to display data on my doughnut chart and I am having issues accessing my data from a nested array. When I use the following it just gives me the selected index of the nested array.

So I am wondering is there something else I need to do the computed data or if there is something I am doing wrong.

here is the computed property

```
countEngagementsByStatus () {
  const selectedWorkflow = this.allWorkflows.filter(workflow => workflow.id === this.workflowKey)

const res = selectedWorkflow.map(({statuses, id}) => ({
 workflow_id: id,
 statuses: statuses.reduce((acc, cur) => {

 const count = this.allEngagements.filter(({workflow_id, status}) => workflow_id === id && status === cur.status).length;

 acc.push(count);

 return acc;

 }, [])
 }))
 return res
 },
```

And on my doughnut chart I am accessing the data. *note removed styling data to clean up the question

```
datasetsfull() {
            return {
                labels: this.mapStatuses[0].statuses,
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Data One',
                    data: [
                           //this is the line I have issues with
                           this.countEngagementsByStatus[0].statuses[0] 
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

here is an image of what I am getting

[image]

Now If I do this

```
data: [
   this.countEngagementsByStatus[0]
     ]
```

**I get this as a result however it cannot access the array of numbers shown**
[image]

So my question is, am I doing something wrong with computed property or am I accessing the data incorrectly or both? Lol

Here is a [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/z9teysa8/61/) To give an idea

Comment: That last data structure should be accessed using `data[0][n]` (where n is your index from 0 to 7). But I'm having some difficulty understanding what you're trying to do and how it's failing.

Comment: @Roy J, what I am trying to do is change the data the doughnut chart reads dynamically. So if you saw the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/z9teysa8/65/) I am changing the data display based off the **workflow selected**. The only place failing is when I try access  all indexes. So if i do `countEngagementsByStatus[0].statuses` the doughnut chart is not access the nested array. And if do `countEngagementsByStatus[0].statuses[0]` it only accesses the first indexed number in the nested array.

Comment: @Roy J in other words instead of `data[0][n]` being (index form 0 to 7) I am only getting `0`

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was I was wrapping the data in an array

```
data: [
      this.countEngagementsByStatus[0].statuses
]
```

I changed it to this

```
data: this.countEngagementsByStatus[0].statuses
```